# IF-ELSE For IP Bindation

Tags: c#, .net

I want that when someone trying to open my application it will auto redirect to https but for some specific ip and localhost use i want to the link open with http.

```
.EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.RootUrl(req =>
                    {
                        var url = "https://" + req.RequestUri.Authority + System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~");

                        return url;
                    });
```

Comment: Typically, this is handled by an external proxy or load balancer, not in the app itself

Comment: Depends what server you use. In general such settings you do in your web server, proxy server, load balancer configuration file.. etc.

Comment: I am Using IIS Server. How to do that in IIS server?